# Laravel+Vite (React) Login Authentication 419 error

Tags: reactjs, laravel, cookies, laravel-blade, vite

i use vite+react
this is my laravel

.env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:wNUxnubkt6TXm17lGBcdhXBWXq4i3btNYdl6YuG4qdw=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:5173
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:5173
SESSION_DOMAIN=
```

cors.php

```
'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:5173')],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

this react

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8000",
    withCredentials: true 
});
```

```
 const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        try { 
           await axios.post('/login',{email,password});
           setEmail("");
           setPassword("");
           useNavigate("/");
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }  
    };
```

But error 419, I also noticed that XSRF-TOKEN is not transmitted to the front

[Laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyNhN.png)
[React+Vite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83WT9.png)

I don't even know what it could be

Comment: Yeah, missing a `TOKEN` on a `POST` request will trigger an `HTTP 419` error. You need to figure out how to send a valid Token, or omit your Login route from CSRF checking (via Middleware: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris)

Answer (score 0):

Import the csrf_token from the Laravel blade template into your React component.

```
import axios from "axios";

const csrfToken = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000",
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrfToken,
  },
});
```

and then use it like this

```
import api from "./api"; // Import the modified Axios instance

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  try {
    await api.post('/login', { email, password });
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
    useNavigate("/");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

you need to ensure that you have the CSRF token meta tag in your Laravel Blade template,

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

also ensure that you have also configured Laravel's CSRF protection properly by checking your `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware in your Laravel app.

Comment: where exactly should it be inserted <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">?

Comment: in the `<head>` section

Comment: react ? if yes, i try do it and it looks like this in f12 content="{{ csrf_token() }}"

Comment: Important question; are you using React in your Laravel project, where a `.blade.php` template would be available? Or are you using React as a standalone front-end and Laravel as an API? If it's the latter, this solution won't work, as `{{ csrf_token() }}` is specifically `.blade.php` syntax.

Comment: i use React as a standalone front-end and Laravel as an API

Comment: @Jonika As react is standalone please investigate laravel sanctum. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#spa-configuration